# Odata Routing and accessing it using Knock out Js

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, odata

I have worked on an application on Asp.Net Mvc4 Internet Application with OData and Knockout Js. Routing in my OData is as follows

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            modelBuilder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
            var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();

            config.Routes.MapODataRoute(routeName: "Odata", routePrefix: "odata", model: model);
```

And Knockout Js as follows

```
 $.getJSON('odata/Products', function (data) {
        self.products(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.value, function (product) {
            var obsProduct = {
                Id: product.Id,
                ProductName: ko.observable(product.ProductName),

                Edit: ko.observable(false),
                Locked: ko.observable(product.Locked)
            }
            self.watchModel(obsProduct, self.modelChanged);
            return obsProduct;
        }));
        self.loading(false);
    });
}
```

But while running an application, it threw an exception as follows

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:57044/Home/odata/Products
```

But when I manually enter the URL `http://localhost:57044/odata/Products` , is is showing the meta data which has all the list of products

But when I enter `http://localhost:57044/Home/odata/Products`(this is a different url from the above), it is throwing a 404 error. How do I fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /Home/odata/Products

--> this is the problem, the HOME, your url is incorrect

```
$.getJSON('/odata/Products', function (data) {
    self.products(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.value, function (product) {
        var obsProduct = {
            Id: product.Id,
            ProductName: ko.observable(product.ProductName),

            Edit: ko.observable(false),
            Locked: ko.observable(product.Locked)
        }
        self.watchModel(obsProduct, self.modelChanged);
        return obsProduct;
    }));
    self.loading(false);
});
```

Comment: To be specific, the problem was that Dayakar was using a relative URL rather than an absolute one, so the actual URL requested would vary according to the current URL of the page.

Comment: @li-raz Thanks, How did I miss that